# What is wrong with this code. it shows "msg is null"

Tags: php, curl

This the code.

```
$data = '{"rewardTime":"20","articleTime":"0","rewardType":"copper_treasure_chest","activeDay":"17","videoTime":"20","specific":"false","userid":"2944210","version":"3","day":"2020-05-07","token":"M2U4ZjQyMWItZmNiYi00NWM4LWJhYWYtOTZhZWEwY2ExODY5"}';
$url = 'https://api.cc.clipclaps.tv/reading/obtainReward';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$result = json_decode($result, true);
echo "$result"."\n";
```

This is the result: 
{"code":4009,"msg":null,"data":null,"date":1588991702039}

It should be msg: `success`

Comment: please add code off api.

Comment: $headers is not defined anywhere.

Comment: You would need to check all requests, send and received, if u need a hand and have got those logged somewhere hit me up in telegram, https://t.me/SuperUserek

Answer (score 2):

You would need to refer to the API's documentation to figure out what Error: `4009` is exactly.

Your code (Curl request) is working, as it is receiving a proper JSON response.. and there is no coding error that I see.

Why the API is responding with an empty result/data field, is specific to the API itself.